# `rails console` hangs when using vendored gems (running in docker)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, bundler

I'm running into a strange issue trying to dockerize a (fairly large) rails app. I'm using the official ruby docker image for now, and mounting my code into the app. Using:

```
docker pull ruby:2.2.4
docker run -it -v $PWD:/code ruby:2.2.4 bash
```

Then in the container I ran:

```
cd /code
bundle install
rails c
```

This works fine (I can't connect to the database obviously since I didn't link it, but rails console otherwise runs normally and loads my app).

However, when I instead run `bundle install --deployment`, then running `rails c` just hangs forever.

Any idea what could cause this?

I was hoping to use a local copy of gems, because we're also using a bunch of npm modules (which install locally into node_modules) so I figured keeping gems in the local directory as well is the most straightforward and has the same persistence between docker runs in the development environment.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind I figured it out - it's not completely hanging just going really really slow thanks to Virtualbox's default type of shared drive. The code is on my OSX filesystem, mounted as a shared drive into Virtualbox (using vagrant), and then mounted as a volume into docker. When the gems are installed into vendor/bundle they all have to be loaded from this slow volume and there are ~150 gems total with all the dependencies.

```
root@fa575694f86a:/code# time echo puts :ok | rails c
Loading development environment (Rails 4.2.1)
Switch to inspect mode.
irb: warn: can't alias context from irb_context.
puts :ok
ok
nil


real    2m0.937s
user    0m2.574s
sys     0m59.985s
```

So it takes 2 whole minutes just to launch rails. I changed vagrant to use an NFS shared volume, and that brings the launch time down to ~12 seconds (literally 10x faster, I'd heard of NFS being 2x faster but this is pretty crazy). Using just `bundle install` to install the gems globally there's no penalty, it's the usual 3-4 second rails load time which is the same thing I get running in OSX.